# glob1 returning empty list - python

Tags: python, glob

I am trying to find files recursively using `glob1` but have not been successful so far. For example if my folder structure is

```
/home/data
   /subdir1
    /subdir1.1
        t1.txt
    /subdir1.2
        t2.txt
   /subdir2
        t3.txt

my_dir = "/home/data"
glob.glob(os.path.join(my_dir, "**/*.txt"), recursive=True)
```

This works as expected. However

```
glob.glob1(my_dir,'**/*.txt')
```

returns an empty list. Why?

Comment: `glob.glob1()` is [undocumented](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/glob.html) and considered private, so much so that CPython [changed code](https://bugs.python.org/issue16620) that relied on it.

Comment: If you use `pathlib` you will get the semantics you want without having to provide the `recursive=True` argument.  Do `from pathlib import Path` then `my_dir = Path('home/data')`.  To get a list of Paths `list(my_dir.glob('**/*.txt'))`.  List with `my_dir` prefixes `[my_dir / p for p in my_dir.glob('**/*.txt')]`. Strings instead of Paths `[str(my_dir / p) for p in my_dir.glob('**/*.txt')]`.  Much of the standard library will accept `Path` objects instead of strings to designate files and directories.

Comment: Thanks @Steven Rumbalski! What I liked about `glob1` was the ability to return file names (without full path) effortlessly. Is there an equivalent method in `pathlib` that provides a similar functionality?

Comment: `[p.name for p in Path('home/data').glob('**/*.txt')]` Note that if the filename is found in subdirectories this is an excellent way to lose that information. Use this only if that's exactly what you want.